# How to get Remote System's IP address?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ip-address

I have built an web Application using Primefaces JSF at JDK 1.7 platform.
In my application i have an IP authentication process, under this process when ever a user log in the IP of the System get Stored in the Database, and when ever user log out the session is closed and the IP Address is cleared from the Database, this is done to done to add the functionality of Single User from Single System.(i.e suppose user log in with one account over a system, now he open up another browser tab and open login page then the user on the basis of the registered IP address for the first account, The user would be restricted from logging in with different account on the same system.)

I have implemented the IP Address Picking up code. and its working fine when tested over the local single system. Now i was checking the system over RMI(Remote Method Invocation) process by installing the application over another System(i.e main server) and  now calling the application from another the remote system, the RMI Process worked perfectly fine, the web application opened Successfully on the another System. Now at the time of the login i faced the actual issue, and the issue was with the IP Address, when i checked out the IP Address in the Database i found that the IP address was not of the remote system from where i was trying to login it was of the Server System where the Application is actually running.

This is he code i have used to pick up the IP Address and its working fine as it is returning an IP Address Value is suppose. 
                InetAddress inetAddress=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                ipAddress=inetAddress.getHostAddress();

Kindly help me at my problem.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Then you have to retrieve the ip address in the web layer and use that as a parameter in the rmi call

Comment: why have been the Question marked -ve?

Comment: Thanks kukeltje for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Solved the issue, The Solution was simple
The problem was with my IP Address Fetching Code

i was using getHostAddress() function to fetch the Ip Address. So it returned me the HOST Address i.e the place where the Application is running.

So for the Solution i have used get the Remote system IP which was fetched using

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if (ipAddress == null) {
ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

This was the solution for me to fetch the IP Address.

Comment: `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");` will give you the Header-Value, which a attacker can set how he like. Because of that, i would always use `request.getRemoteAddr()` and log the `X-FORWARDED-FOR`-IP seperatly.